# need mechanism to detect client connections to portable hotspot

Tags: android

My android phone is acting as a portable hotspot to which several clients may connect.
Please suggest a mechanism to detect/listen/receive notification whenever a client connects or disconnects to/from the hotspot.

All clients connecting to the hotspot are serial device servers. Since my tablet/phone(hotspot) is on the move, clients keep disconnecting and reconnecting to it depending on the range, and I need to track their connection status.

Currentl approach: I am executing a thread that sends udp discovery requests from the android phone, receives responses from clients and store their details in a Map.
What I am looking for is a more efficeint way to detect disconnections and reconnections as and when they happen.

Comment: What have you tried? It is way easier for us to guide you if you already know what direction to go.

Comment: All clients connecting to the hotspot are serial device servers.

Comment: @gobernador All clients connecting to the hotspot are serial device servers. Since my tablet(hotspot) is on the move, clients keep disconnecting and reconnecting depending on the range, and I need to track their connection status.
Currentl approach: I am executing a thread that sends udp discovery requests from the android phone, receives responses from clients and store their details in a Map.  
What I am looking for is a more efficeint way to detect disconnections and reconnections as and when they happen.

Answer (score 1):

this might be helpful?
http://www.whitebyte.info/android/android-wifi-hotspot-manager-class

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.